# Macro in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sheet 1 

E-Code  E-Name
11621   Hari
12205   Dass
11709   Boss
11913   Pass
11755   Test

Sheet 2         

E-Code          
11621           
11709           
11913           
11755           
12205
```

I want to run a macro which automatically do the vlookup function in sheet 2 against the E-Code which are unique fields.

The macro which i have created is as below. However when i change the data it is not working.

```
Sub Macro()

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet1!C[-1]:C,2,0)"
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet1!C1:C2,2,0)"
Range("B2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B3:B6").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Fair enough, but we are not going to write that for you. We are more than glad to help you out with a problem you face though. So what did you try until now? Anything you can show us? Anything in particular that doesn't work? The more details you can add to your question, the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: i Have update the same in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code. It is working fine. However, if you increase the no of rows it will not take into account. Please find the below code which will find the no of rows in Sheet1 and Sheet2.

```
Sub Macro1()

  Dim sht1 As Worksheet
  Dim sht2 As Worksheet

  Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")

  Sh1Rows = sht1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  sh2rows = sht2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  sht2.Range("B2") = "=Vlookup(A2," & sht1.Name & "!" & sht1.Range("A2:B" & sh2rows).Address & ",2,false)"
   sht2.Range("B2").Copy sht2.Range("B2:B" & sh2rows)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, it is perfectly working when the no. of rows are matching in both the sheets. However say in the 1st sheet i have having data for 10 rows, and in the 2nd sheet i am having data for 5 rows this macro is showing error data in values which are present in the rows after 5 in sheet 1.